# Error 502 when attempting to bring my website online

Tags: node.js, apache, express, raspberry-pi, lamp

I am having some difficulty getting a personal website to operate correctly.  I am getting 502 errors and am not sure how to correct them.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Proxy Error)
```

I have two domains that I purchased from Google Domains as well as my own Webserver built on the Raspberry Pi.  In fact, I have 3 Raspberry Pi's.  RP-Main acts as a reverse-proxy server using Apache to route requests for Domain A to RP-0 and Domain B to RP-1.  The Raspberry Pi's are using a LAMP stack to serve the websites.

The website for RP-0 consists of a single file, `index.php`, which shows the date and time.

The website for RP-1 is a Node.Js/Express application website and this is the one I am having a problem with.

I created the website on an Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual Machine using Virtual Box.  This is acting as my development server.  I completed the website a few days ago with the intention of transferring it to my Production server, the aforementioned RP-1.

At this point in time I am not using any transpiling or bundling, my plan is to get a working application, and then add in those features later. Also, my plan is to use NPM PM2 to keep my website live. So I copied all of the files from the Development server to the Production Server and started the website using `npm start` as I did on my development server.

Now on my main computer when I go to my domain, the website does load but it appears it is only serving some of the static files.  For example, I have an image in the `public/img` folder that is indeed appearing.  However, the css files do not appear to be loading and they are located in public/css.  Also, it appears that JQuery is not working either.

In troubleshooting this issue, Chrome tools is showing 502 errors, however, when I look at the actual error, the path to the static files is correct.

I have read some articles suggesting that the issue might be caching.  I know on a basic level what caching refers to but not how to implement it for my website.

If there are any individuals that have successfully implemented what I am trying to do I would sure appreciate any knowledge or advice you may have.

Here are my default.conf files:

RP Main: Internal IP Address - 192.168.1.105 - This is the master reverse proxy RPi

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName              www.abc.net
    ServerAlias             www.abc.net
    ProxyPreserveHost       on
    ProxyPass               / http://192.168.1.104
    ProxyPassReverse        / http://192.168.1.104
</VirtualHost>
```

RP - 1: Internal IP Address - 192.168.1.104 - This RPi has the Node.js/Express app running on http://localhost:3000

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName            www.abc.net
    ServerAlias           www.abc.net
    ProxyPreserveHost     on
    ProxyPass             / http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverse      / http://localhost:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you for reading this rather lengthy post!!

Comment: is it 502 or 505 ?

Comment: you should show us your apache conf too... are you using apache to proxy your node app?  If not, you should really consider that option.